# Fetch in react native doesn't send the post with codeIgniter API

Tags: codeigniter, react-native

Fetch post is not working with the json api coded with codeIgniter. The get method works but there's issue in post method. The key is not recognized between the react native and code igniter. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou

```
 fetch('http://zzz.com/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
     username: 'abc',
   }),
 })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(responseJson => {
   console.log('responseJson', responseJson);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('fetchError', error);
 });
```

CodeIgniter controller

```
public function login()

{
    $un = $this->input->post('username'); //why doesn't the key 'username' is working here
    echo json_encode($un);
}
```

CONSOLE LOG:

```
responseJson false
```

Updates:

1)Using json_decode, gives error 
"fetchError SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"

```
public function login()
{
   $Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), false);
     echo $Data;
 }
```

2)Using json_encode gives following outcomes:
responseJson {"username":"abc"}

```
public function login()
{
   $Data = json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'), false);
     echo $Data;
 }
```

## Update 1:

1) Using only file_get_contents gives the output as: responseJson {username: "abc"}

```
public function login()
{
    $Data = (file_get_contents('php://input'));
    echo $Data;
 }
```

2)using var_dump and json_decode in server code, it gives following error in the app console

```
public function login()
{
    $Data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    var_dump ($Data);
 }
```

Error:

```
fetchError SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryCallOne (E:\zzz\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37)
    at E:\zzz\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123
    at E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:295
    at _callTimer (E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:152)
    at _callImmediatesPass (E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:200)
    at Object.callImmediates (E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:464)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:320)
    at E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135
    at MessageQueue.__guard (E:\zzz\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297)
```

console log the response as following gives the array in app console:

```
fetch('http://zzz.com/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     username: 'abc',
   })
})
.then((response) => console.log('response', response))
```

Console:

```
response 
Response {type: "default", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}
headers:Headers {map: {…}}
ok:true
status:200
statusText:undefined
type:"default"
url:"http://zzz.com/login"
_bodyInit:"array(1) {↵  ["username"]=>↵  string(3) "abc"↵}↵"
_bodyText:"array(1) {↵  ["username"]=>↵  string(3) "abc"↵}↵"
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Does CodeIgniter have a request body JSON deserializer though?

Comment: Most probably not, so you may have to read the raw stream using something like `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)`. `echo` that in the login action to see the result. I'd also add, to sanitize the input there before doing anything further with it.

Comment: @kadeer using echoing json_decode gives nothing but if I use         $a = json_encode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        echo $a; It gives the output as fetchResponsee {"username":"abc"}

Comment: Please have a look at the updates above

Comment: Hi, pardon me, I should have suggested `var_dump` in place of `echo`. If you're getting an "Unexpected end of JSON input", in the login action, see the output of this then: `file_get_contents('php://input')`. That should return the content of  POST in it's raw form. Ensure what you can see is valid JSON.

Comment: Hello @kadeer  it gives the following output: {username: "abc"} . And plz have a look at the Update 1 as well

Comment: As it seems, dumping the `file_get_contents('php://input')` reveals the content of the input to be the data you sent in the body value in the AJAX options. You should be able to `json_decode` the input into a valid PHP array. Still not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `same-origin` mode like below :

```
fetch('http://zzz.com/login', {
   method: 'POST',
   credentials: 'same-origin',
   mode: 'same-origin',
   headers: {
     'Accept': 'application/json',
     'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
   },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     username: 'abc',
   }),
 })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(responseJson => {
   console.log('responseJson', responseJson);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('fetchError', error);
 });
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. Plz have a look at the updates above. Thankyou

Comment: Try to send data without json stringify and then decode
 body: {username: 'abc'},

Answer (score 0):

From the front end, send the data as a form data (as shown below).

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("name", "RandomData");
formData.append("operation", "randomOperation");
```

In your Codeigniter controller, receive it as...

```
$name = $this->input->post("name");
$operation = $this->input->post("operation");
```